# Newtonian Mechanics problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> The ball of mass $m$ is given a speed of $v_a = \sqrt{3gr}$ at position $A$. When it reaches $B$, the cord hits the small peg $P$ after which the ball describes a smaller circular path. Determine the position $x$ of $P$ so that the ball will be able to reach point $C$.

[image]

**My Work**

Let $T$ represent kinetic energy and $V$ potential energy. Let $O$ be the datum for gravitational potential energy.

$T_1 + V_1 = T_2 + V_2$

$1/2m(3gr) - mgr = mg(r-x)$

$3/2r - r = r-x$

$x = r-3/2r + r$

$x = 1/2r$

However the correct answer is $x = 2/3r$. What's my mistake? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T_2$ isn't 0. The ball will be moving sideways.

You will need to calculate the minimum speed that will keep the cord straight.

Comment: How would I find the minimum speed?

Comment: @dfg centrifugal force, $\dfrac{mv^2}{r-x}$ should be equal to weight $mg$.

Comment: If the ball moves in a circle, then $a = v^2/(r-x)$. Think about what the cord does if $a > 1g$ or $a < 1g$.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya  
Sorry, I thought I understood, but I don't. Why can't a<1g? I get why a>1g - because string's can only exert tension forces right?

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya You have it right. Suppose the ball moves slowly. Then a < g. But gravity alone makes a = g. You would need an upward acceleration to make a < g. The cord can't do it.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is 1/2r. 3/2 r cannot possibly be the correct answer because you only had a string of length r to begin with.

T1 + V1 = Tf + Vf

1/2m(VA)^2 = mgr + mg(r-x)

3/2mgr = mg(2r -x)

Therefore, x = 1/2r as you have discovered. Your answer is correct and the solutions manual is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I mean't $2/3r$. I can assure you its right though.